# C# ComboBox Selected Value returns Null, Item and Value both from Database

Tags: c#, combobox

I added Employee LastName and First name to a combobox which is working, Eg. LastName, FirstName.. The value should be set as EmpID so that when I'm selecting an Item, EmpId will be return as value

```
conn.Open(); 
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select (LastName + ', ' + FirstName) AS Employee,EmpID from Employee ", conn))
using (SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        ListItem ComboItem = new ListItem();
        ComboItem.Text = rdr["Employee"].ToString();
        //ComboItem.Value = rdr["EmpID"].ToString();

        ComboItem.Value = rdr["EmpID"].ToString() ;
        GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(ComboItem);  
        //GrpEmpCBox.Items.Add(rdr["Employee"].ToString());
    }
}
```

But when I'm getting the value of it returns null.

```
private void btnRunReport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    EmployeeTimecardReport rptEmpTimecard = new EmployeeTimecardReport();
    rptEmpTimecard.Employee = GrpEmpCBox.SelectedValue.ToString(); //<--- this returns null
}
```

is this possible? I'm trying not to use databinding

my combobox properties:

DataSource: none

DisplayMember: none

Value Member: none

DropDownStyle: DropDownList

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `DisplayMember` and `ValueMember` properties instead.

There are many ways you could implement this... here's one:

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "Item1";     // the value of the selected item
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Item2";   // the field to display to the user

var emps = new List<Tuple<int, string>>();

while (rdr.Read())
    emps.Add(Tuple.Create(Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmpID"]), rdr["Employee"].ToString()));

comboBox1.DataSource = emps;
```

Then to display the value of the selected item:

```
var selectedValue = comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
```

---

I'll add a second example to demonstrate what those properties do.

Say you have an Employee class you created.

```
public class Employee
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public DateTime HireDate { get; set; }
}
```

And then you pull back a bunch of data from the Employee table in the database...

```
var emps = new List<Employee>();

while (rdr.Read())
    emps.Add(new Employee(ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["EmpID"]),
                          Name = rdr["Employee"].ToString(),
                          Age = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["Age"]),
                          HireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(rdr["Hired"])));

comboBox1.DataSource = emps;
```

You can pick two properties from your class to (1) display to the user (DisplayMember) and (2) act as the underlying value (ValueMember).

```
comboBox1.ValueMember = "ID";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

Now you can get those values using `comboBox1.SelectedValue` and `comboBox1.Text`, respectively. Or you can just get the entire `Employee` record, which is stored in `comboBox1.SelectedItem`.

Comment: it's working.. may I know the purpose of ValueMember and DisplayMember??

Answer (score 0):

This if you Used the **DisplayMember and ValueMember** properties and still get Null Error

You must set the DataSource property of your Combobox control if you want to use the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties.
**Code Example**

```
List<(int,string)> F = new List<(int,string)>();
         
           
            DataTable d = ConnandDisConnMode.Program.DisConnectedMode();
            for (int i = 0; i < d.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                F.Add(((int)d.Rows[i]["id"], d.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()));
            }

            comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
            foreach (var item in F)
            {
                ComboboxItem i = new ComboboxItem();
                i.Text = item.Item2;
                i.Value = item.Item1;
                comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
```

This would make the Combobox.SelectedValue  Return NUll
You have to change The Code to be like this

```
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "Text";
            comboBox1.ValueMember = "Value";
            List<ComboboxItem> z = new List<ComboboxItem>();
            foreach (var item in F)
            {
                ComboboxItem i = new ComboboxItem();
                i.Text = item.Item2;
                i.Value = item.Item1;
                z.Add(i);
                //comboBox1.Items.Add(i);
            }
            comboBox1.DataSource = z;
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this problem was caused by accidentally calling `InitializeComponent()` of the whole form twice, once *before* and once *after* having set the combo box's `ValueMember` and `DisplayMember`.